# MYSQL: how to retrieve the data with VIEWS (software doesn't support Table Aliases)

Tags: mysql

I want to know how can I get the result below WITHOUT using TABLE ALIASES. We can use MYSQL VIEWS though. I have the following code that works, but we have to get rid of the TABLE ALIASES Somehow. (The software that we use, don't allow Table Aliases)

The problem Is getting the StopAddress where StopAddress = Max(SamplingEnd) grouped per date. If that makes sense  - Look at the "Desired Result to see how I want it to look.

Thanks in advance for your Time - really appreciate it!!

```
SELECT 
Max(samplingend) AS StopTime, 
Min(starthours)  AS StartHours, 
Max(endhours)    AS EndHours, 
(SELECT T2.stopaddress
FROM   QEventReport T2
    WHERE  Date(T2.samplingend) = Date(T1.samplingend) 
    ORDER  BY T2.samplingend DESC 
    LIMIT  1) AS StopAddress 
FROM   QEventReport T1 
GROUP  BY userid, 
      name, 
      Date(samplingend) 
ORDER  BY Date(samplingend), 
      userid;
```

Desired result:

```
+---------------------+------------+----------+-------------+
| StopTime            | StartHours | EndHours | StopAddress |
+---------------------+------------+----------+-------------+
| 2016-03-22 20:00:00 | 09:00:00   | 08:00:59 | Namibia     |
| 2016-03-23 21:00:00 | 05:00:00   | 23:00:00 | India       |
+---------------------+------------+----------+-------------+
```

TABLE 'QEventReport'

```
+-------------+--------+------+------------+----------+---------------------+
| StopAddress | UserID | Name | StartHours | EndHours | SamplingEnd         |
+-------------+--------+------+------------+----------+---------------------+
| Ermelo      |      1 | Lisa | 09:00:00   | 08:00:59 | 2016-03-22 09:00:00 |
| Balizza     |      1 | Lisa | 10:00:00   | 08:00:59 | 2016-03-22 10:00:00 |
| CT          |      1 | Lisa | 11:00:00   | 08:00:59 | 2016-03-22 11:00:00 |
| PE          |      1 | Lisa | 12:00:00   | 08:00:59 | 2016-03-22 12:00:00 |
| JHB         |      1 | Lisa | 13:00:00   | 08:00:59 | 2016-03-22 13:00:00 |
| Durban      |      1 | Lisa | 14:00:00   | 08:00:59 | 2016-03-22 14:00:00 |
| East London |      1 | Lisa | 15:00:00   | 08:00:59 | 2016-03-22 15:00:00 |
| Pretoria    |      1 | Lisa | 16:00:00   | 08:00:59 | 2016-03-22 16:00:00 |
| KZN         |      1 | Lisa | 17:00:00   | 08:00:59 | 2016-03-22 17:00:00 |
| Pinetown    |      1 | Lisa | 18:00:00   | 08:00:59 | 2016-03-22 18:00:00 |
| Krugersdorp |      1 | Lisa | 19:00:00   | 08:00:59 | 2016-03-22 19:00:00 |
| Namibia     |      1 | Lisa | 20:00:00   | 08:00:59 | 2016-03-22 20:00:00 |
| Panama      |      1 | Lisa | 05:00:00   | 00:20:16 | 2016-03-23 05:00:00 |
| Bali        |      1 | Lisa | 05:00:00   | 00:20:16 | 2016-03-23 04:00:00 |
| India       |      1 | Lisa | 08:00:00   | 23:00:00 | 2016-03-23 21:00:00 |
| China       |      1 | Lisa | 10:00:00   | 21:00:00 | 2016-03-23 20:00:00 |
+-------------+--------+------+------------+----------+---------------------+
```